# Endless background spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, loops, sprite-kit

I'm trying to make endless background with the method from book 2D iOS & tvOS Games by Ray Wenderlich and my game crash with reason "Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent" that happened because the child is already on scene and the loop try to add it again, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks!

```
    func backgroundNode() -> SKSpriteNode {
    // 1
    let backgroundNode = SKSpriteNode()
    backgroundNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
    backgroundNode.name = "background"
    // 2
    background1.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
    background1.size = self.frame.size
    background1.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    backgroundNode.addChild(background1)
    // 3
    background2.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
    background1.size = self.frame.size
    background2.position =
        CGPoint(x: background1.size.width, y: 0)
    backgroundNode.addChild(background2)
    // 4
    backgroundNode.size = CGSize(
        width: background1.size.width + background2.size.width,
        height: background1.size.height)

    return backgroundNode
}

for i in 0...1 {
let background = backgroundNode()
background.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
background.position =
CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i)*background.size.width, y: 0)
background.name = "background"
addChild(background)
}
```

Comment: can you please post a bit more? I don't see any errors like that in this code so far. Also, post the code where the error occurs. You can add an exception breakpoint to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through your for loop twice, so you're adding the same child twice.

Change the first line of your for loop to this: `for i in 0..<1 {`

When using the `for i in x...y` you start at x and go up to *and including* y.

Comment: But now background repeat only one time and it's not endless.

Comment: How can I create endless background with SKCameraNode?

Comment: I think your background wouldn't have been endless anyways since you were only looping through twice. I would put in a check in the update method that if the background's position is past a certain point, create a new image and position it after the first image. Once the first image is off the screen, remove it from the scene, and repeat.